# Can my NAS work behind the captive portal of my student dorm?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, ethernet, nas, captive-portal

i live in a student dorm and the network have a captive portal that asks for credentials. I have a **iomega ix200** and i don't know how to access it even in the same private network without being linked by ethernet directly.

**i tried to spoof** the IP of my laptop on my nas while configuring it linked to it on ethernet, after getting my IP through the dhcp and captive portal **and** using the mac address of my nas and plug it in on ethernet and then i plugged my nas on the network and I still couldn't access it...

I also tried **to ask to the support** but they didn't had a clue of what a NAS is...

Their **nginx** version has multiple exploits but I don't think i should consider to take this path haha

If someone has an idea of how I could manage to access it even inside the private network this could help me a lot !

Thanks

Comment: Not going to work.

Comment: A comment isn’t an answer

Comment: Not sure what answer we can provide because we have no idea how the network is setup. I'll just say some captive portals are based on DNS. So you can manually configure IP and just use your own DNS. However I highly suggest you just use a router then spoof the router with your own MAC and put yourself in the routers "DMZ" then you'll see the NAS but no one else will. You could also get a USB to Ethernet adapter.

Comment: @jdwolf, do you think I could do it using my desktop windows computer ? Like setting a bridge of my pc to my nas with a ethernet adapter and then sending requests to reconnect as soon as i disconnect using wget with ubuntu wsl ? I'll find a way to know more about the network. to bring up more hypothesis but some of them sounds illegal lol

Comment: @Coach Carti Yes bridging is a great way to do this. Keep in mind the bridged adaptor must either have a interface specfic DHCP or you'd have to setup the NAS with a static IP. I mainly suggest a router because many people have extras laying around while usb to Ethernet adapters not so much.

Comment: Thanks a lot @jdwolf ! I made some reasearchs and found some travel routers that are multi purposes (bridging and stuff). I'll buy one to do my own subnet inside the network to connect all my devices to my vpn on my vps to go a little bit further ! But to stay authenticated on the captive portal can I have my desktop pc to run a script on a vm to send requests to stay authenticated or should i invest in a raspb or something like that ?